# "decode" an approximation of sin Taylor series

Tags: c, trigonometry, taylor-series

I'm using Taylor series to compute `sin()`. The Taylor series for the sin are:

[image: sin taylor series]

The implementation I'm using looks like follows:

```
float sine(float x, int j)
{
    float val = 1;

    for (int k = j - 1; k >= 0; --k)
        val = 1 - x*x/(2*k+2)/(2*k+3)*val;

    return x * val;
}
```

As far I understand, that code is an approximation of `j` terms of the polynomial (In other words, the approximation is a sumatory from zero to `j` instead of from zero to ∞), `k` is `n` in the formula, and of course `x` is `x`.

I'm trying to understand that implementation, that is, the transformation from the formula above to the code. My goal is to write the same kind of implementation for the `cos()` series.

**Could you help me to understand that?**

Comment: Consider the ratio of two successive terms.

Comment: It might be a [Chebyshev approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomial), not a Taylor one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a McLaurin series, but it is written so as to reduce the number of computations exploiting a recurrence formula for the general term of the series.

The version for cosine is the following (together with a simple test harness):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float cosine(float x, int j)
{
    float val = 1;
    for (int k = j - 1; k >= 0; --k)
        val = 1 - x*x/(2*k+2)/(2*k+1)*val;
    return val;
}

int main( void )
{
    for( double x = 0.0; x <= 1.57; x += 0.1 )
    {
        printf("%10g    %10g    %10g\n", x, cos(x), cosine(x, 5));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** (replaced ugly text math with images created with LaTeX)

To understand the trick, let's focus on the `sine` example and recall the McLaurin expansion of the sine function:

[image: McLaurin expansion of sine function]

Now let's perform the expansion up to the 5th term (N=5), neglect the remainder R and perform some rewriting involving factorizations of x<sup>2</sup> terms. The resulting steps are described below, where rewritten subexpressions are marked with a number in square brackets:

[image: rewriting steps]

The C function is just the implementation of this recursive rewriting from the bottom up, i.e. what appears as the last step in the above schema is computed first in the `sine` function (the example is relative to a call with `j==4`, so that the loop variable `k` starts with a value of `3` and goes down to `0`) .

Comment: Could explain me the rewrite process step by step? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly math notation. I really miss LaTeX support here! :-)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I miss latex too, thats why I posted an image with the formula

Comment: Finally I found some time to replace that ugly math with nicer images.

Comment: Thanks! That improves the answer a lot!

Comment: This grouping of terms is a trick that already Newton used. Today it is most commonly (and falsly) named "Horner scheme" (of polynomial evaluation).